# SQL GROUP BY CASE statement with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a column that looks something like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4)
    ELSE 0
END AS some_product
```

And I would like to put it in my GROUP BY clause, but this seems to cause problems because there is an aggregate function in column.  Is there a way to GROUP BY a column alias such as `some_product` in this case, or do I need to put this in a subquery and group on that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

My guess is that you don't really want to `GROUP BY` some_product.

The **answer to:** "Is there a way to `GROUP BY` a column alias such as some_product in this case, or do I need to put this in a subquery and group on that?" **is:** You can not `GROUP BY` a column alias.

The `SELECT` clause, where column aliases are assigned, is not processed until after the `GROUP BY` clause. An inline view or common table expression (CTE) could be used to make the results available for grouping.

Inline view:

```
select ...
from (select ... , CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4) ELSE 0 END AS some_product
   from ...
   group by col1, col2 ... ) T
group by some_product ...
```

CTE:

```
with T as (select ... , CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4) ELSE 0 END AS some_product
   from ...
   group by col1, col2 ... )
select ...
from T
group by some_product ...
```

Answer (score 54):

While [Shannon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209151/241211) is technically correct, it looks like overkill.

The simple solution is that you need to put your summation outside of the `case` statement.
This should do the trick:

```
sum(CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN col3*col4 ELSE 0 END) AS some_product
```

Basically, your old code tells SQL to execute the `sum(X*Y)` for each line individually (leaving each line with its own answer that can't be grouped).

The code line I have written takes the sum product, which is what you want.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to use this method over Shannon's answer involving a CTE? Thanks

Comment: For general case statements, you'd want to use Shannon's answer. This one relies on sums of 0 being 0.

Answer (score 14):

I think this answer is pretty simple:

```
SELECT    
CASE
    WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4)
    ELSE 0
END AS some_product
FROM some_table
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4)
    ELSE 0
END
```

You can put the CASE STATEMENT in the GROUP BY verbatim (minus the alias column name)

Answer (score 6):

If you are grouping by some other value, then instead of what you have,

write it as

```
Sum(CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN SUM(col3*col4) ELSE 0 END) as SumSomeProduct
```

If, otoh, you want to `group By` the internal expression, `(col3*col4)` then

write the `group By` to match the expression w/o the `SUM`...

```
Select Sum(Case When col1 > col2 Then col3*col4 Else 0 End) as SumSomeProduct
From ...

Group By Case When col1 > col2 Then col3*col4 Else 0 End
```

Finally, if you want to group By the actual aggregate

```
Select SumSomeProduct, Count(*), <other aggregate functions>
From (Select <other columns you are grouping By>, 
      Sum(Case When col1 > col2 
          Then col3*col4 Else 0 End) as SumSomeProduct
      From Table
      Group By <Other Columns> ) As Z
Group by SumSomeProduct
```

Comment: You aggregate *over* a grouping. Not *on* the grouping.

Comment: Whoever upvoted, it's wrong. Try something similar yourself... "give me the sum of 2 values multiplied, grouped by 2 other values, and also group on the aggregate of my group".

Comment: After Charles' edit: your inner query will only ever return one row, making your outer grouping meaningless...

Comment: @gbn, thanks, yes, I left out the other (implied) columns he is grouping by, but did not mention in the question... I'll edit to correct

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, I am able to GROUP BY a "case when" column in my aggregate table. All you have to do is put 'GROUP BY calculated some_product'. Just put 'calculated' and a space before the column name. Works for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note, that the question is not about SAS.