# how to use case statement in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I have following case statements in my SELECT clause, also I
 have a group by clause...
         So, Is it okay to specify UF.CONT_PID & UF.M_STATUS_CD  in my
 GROUP BY Clause ?         I need to specify the entire CASE statement
 in GROUP BY ?

```
 CASE WHEN UF.CONT_PID IN    
 ('04007005', '01019045','01019046') OR 
 (UF.M_STATUS_CD IN ('01', '02') 
 THEN    
 1    
 ELSE    
0    
 END
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  SQL is pretty good about reporting syntax errors...

Comment: similar question...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208854/sql-group-by-case-statement-with-aggregate-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than repeat the expression, you could do:

```
SELECT col /*, other cols */ FROM
(
  SELECT col = CASE WHEN /*...long-winded expression...*/ 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END /*, other cols */
  FROM dbo.table
) AS x
GROUP BY col;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can group by in two ways:

```
GROUP BY UF.CONT_PID, UF.M_STATUS_CD
```

OR

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN UF.CONT_PID IN ('04007005', '01019045','01019046') OR (UF.M_STATUS_CD IN ('01', '02') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But keep in mind that these are very different groupings.