# Using case with aggregate function & group by clauses

Tags: sql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

I have a query using CASE with aggregate function and group by clause, like this

```
SELECT
A
,B
,C
,CASE
     WHEN <COLUMN_NAME_A> IS NOT NULL 
     THEN (SUM(<COLUMN_NAME_B>) * <COLUMN_NAME_A>)
          ELSE 0
END AS <ALIAS>
FROM <TARGET_TABLE>
GROUP BY
A
,B
,C
,<ALIAS>
```

and I got an error "GROUP BY and WITH...BY clauses may not contain aggregate"

then, I change my script (exclude  from group by)

```
SELECT
A
,B
,C
,CASE
     WHEN <COLUMN_NAME_A> IS NOT NULL 
     THEN (SUM(<COLUMN_NAME_B>) * <COLUMN_NAME_A>)
          ELSE 0
END AS <ALIAS>
FROM <TARGET_TABLE>
GROUP BY
A
,B
,C
```

and still got an error "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group"

please help me to understand why  must be part of group by, 
and what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208854/sql-group-by-case-statement-with-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
A
,B
,C
,SUM(CASE
     WHEN <COLUMN_NAME_A> IS NOT NULL 
     THEN <COLUMN_NAME_B> * <COLUMN_NAME_A>
          ELSE 0
END) AS <ALIAS>
FROM <TARGET_TABLE>
GROUP BY
A
,B
,C
```

But your CASE statement have no sense. If `<COLUMN_NAME_A>` is `NULL` i.e. `<COLUMN_NAME_B> * <COLUMN_NAME_A>` is `NULL` it will be ignored by `SUM` aggregate.
Use this instead.

```
SELECT
A
,B
,C
,ISNULL(SUM(<COLUMN_NAME_B> * <COLUMN_NAME_A>), 0) AS <ALIAS>
FROM <TARGET_TABLE>
GROUP BY
A
,B
,C
```

`ISNULL` used in case when no non-null value retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
SELECT  A
,B
,C
,CASE
     WHEN <COLUMN_NAME_A> IS NOT NULL 
     THEN (SUM(<COLUMN_NAME_B>) * <COLUMN_NAME_A>)
          ELSE 0
END AS <ALIAS>
FROM <TARGET_TABLE>
GROUP BY
A
,B
,C
,<COLUMN_NAME_A>
```