# SQL CASE Output

Tags: sql

```
select to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy-mm') as entered_date, 
CASE
    when T_12916_VIA = 'E'   then 'Internet'
    when T_12916_VIA = 'R'   then 'Store'
    when (T_12916_VIA in ('M','F','P') or T_12916_VIA is null) then 'All Others'
end as VIA_CODE,
count(*)
from cmlbrc.applicants
where to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy') >= '2010'
group by to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy-mm'), T_12916_VIA
order by 1,2;
```

The code above gives me multiple rows as output for yyyy-mm.  Why wouldn't the "All Others" group into one row?
2010-05 All Others    278
2010-05 All Others    975
2010-05 All Others    223
2010-05 Internet     5124
2010-05 Store       19641

Thanks
Dan

Comment: because you are grouping by `T_12916_VIA` which holds the values `'E', 'R', 'M', 'F', 'P'` and it's on those that the records are grouped. you need to wrap this in another select statment which then groups by via_code see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1209151/1114171)

Comment: Please use better english. Question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your `CASE` statement to your `GROUP BY` which should remove the duplicates:

```
select to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy-mm') as entered_date, 
   CASE
       when T_12916_VIA = 'E'   then 'Internet'
       when T_12916_VIA = 'R'   then 'Store'
       when (T_12916_VIA in ('M','F','P') or T_12916_VIA is null) then 'All Others'
   end as VIA_CODE,
   count(*)
from cmlbrc.applicants
where to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy') >= '2010'
group by to_char(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,'yyyy-mm'), 
   CASE
       when T_12916_VIA = 'E'   then 'Internet'
       when T_12916_VIA = 'R'   then 'Store'
       when (T_12916_VIA in ('M','F','P') or T_12916_VIA is null) then 'All Others'
   end
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: @99Valk -- np, glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer follwing script:

You need to specify the case block in group by clause also.

```
Create Table #Temp1(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE smalldatetime,T_12916_VIA char(1))

insert into #Temp1 ( T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE,T_12916_VIA )
Select dateadd( d,id,getdate()), case When a.ID <= 10 Then 'E'
When a.ID <= 20 Then 'R'
When a.ID > 20 Then 'M' End
  from Tally As a
Where a.ID < 30
Order by a.ID 

Select * from #Temp1

select Year(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE) as entered_date, 
CASE
    when T_12916_VIA = 'E'   then 'Internet'
    when T_12916_VIA = 'R'   then 'Store'
    when (T_12916_VIA in ('M','F','P') or T_12916_VIA is null) then 'All Others'
end as VIA_CODE,
count(*)
from #Temp1
group by Year(T_12895_DET_ENTERED_DATE) , 
CASE
    when T_12916_VIA = 'E'   then 'Internet'
    when T_12916_VIA = 'R'   then 'Store'
    when (T_12916_VIA in ('M','F','P') or T_12916_VIA is null) then 'All Others'
end 
order by 1,2
```