# SQL GROUP BY with a SUM CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that there are a lot of question like this:

[SQL GROUP BY CASE statement with aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208854/sql-group-by-case-statement-with-aggregate-function)

but I've tried doing:

```
with T as (select col1 , SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN col3 ELSE 0 END) AS Totale
   from tabella
   group by col1, col2)
select col1, Totale
from T
group by col1, Totale
```

but I'm getting

```
col1  |  Totale
---------------
   1       0
   1      70
   2       0
   2      90
```

Instead of:

```
 col1  |  Totale
---------------
   1      70
   2      90
```

What's wrong with that?

**UPDATE:**

My bad, I try to keep it simple but I've overdone it.. What I've to do is:

```
with T as (select col1 , SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN col3 ELSE 0 END) AS TotaleA,
                         SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN col3 ELSE 0 END) AS TotaleB,
                          (...)
       from tabella
       group by col1, col2)
    select col1, TotaleA, TotaleB
    from T
    group by col1, TotaleA, TotaleB
```

And the solution is to do without col2 in the grouping... I was afraid getting "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause", but it's not.. Can I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: Well your final query is producing results that are accurate with the code. Probably remove the col2 from the group by inside your cte. With out more details though it is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also approach this problem by using a subquery:

```
SELECT 
       col1,
       SUM(A) TotalA,
       SUM(B) TotalB
FROM 
(
       select col1, 
              CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN col3 ELSE 0 END A,
              CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN col3 ELSE 0 END B
       from  tabella
) t
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. Not sure why you have this wrapped in a cte but why not make it simpler?

```
select col1 
    , SUM(col3) AS Totale
from tabella
where col2 = 1
group by col1
```