# Group by Range SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**UPDATE!!!!**

I have the following SQL query built with its respective output:

[image]

[image]

I would like to effectively add labels to each of the aggregations like below:

```
coupon percent   |   income level
-----------------------------------
 .023434355      |   0-20000
 .054888999      |   20000-35000
 .010000002      |   35000-100000
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `CASE` statement to your `GROUP BY` something like

```
GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN storeAvgIncome <= 20000 THEN '0-20000' 
    WHEN storeAvgIncome > 20000 AND storeAvgIncome <=  35000 THEN '20000-35000' 
    WHEN storeAvgIncome > 35000 AND storeAvgIncome <= 100000 THEN '35000-100000'
    END
```

Then add the same to your `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN storeAvgIncome <= 20000 THEN '0-20000' 
        WHEN storeAvgIncome > 20000 AND storeAvgIncome <=  35000 THEN '20000-35000' 
        WHEN storeAvgIncome > 35000 AND storeAvgIncome <= 100000 THEN '35000-100000'
        END AS [income level]
```

Comment: Footnote: You can do this as long as your CASE statement [does not contain an aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1208854/477563).

Comment: I actually got a bit farther before I saw your reply. Now that I have the ranges set up in the case statement, how do I get the actual ranges themselves to show up as effective row labels like described above? I cannot simply add the `dimStore.storeAvgIncome` to the select statement, so how do I get my case statement then values to show up for the respective rows?