# Query Builder of ReportViewer Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'END'.?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, reportviewer

I'm trying create a Query using Query Builder of ReportViewer but when I try execute does thrown an exception, using `PHPMyAdmin` does execute alright.

How could I do this ?

**trying**

```
SELECT e.id, e.tipoOperacao, e.historico, 
SUM(CASE WHEN e.tipoOperacao = 'E' THEN e.qtdTransacao ELSE 0 END) AS QTDENTRADA,
SUM(CASE WHEN e.tipoOperacao = 'S' THEN e.qtdTransacao ELSE 0 END) AS QTDSAIDA,
e.dtTransacao, e.valorTransacao, e.usuario, e.produto_id, p.id, p.descricao, 
p.valorCusto, p.valorVenda, p.controlarEstoque, p.qtdEntEstoque, p.estoqueMin, 
p.estoqueMax, p.status, p.imagem, p.catproduto_id, p.unidproduto_id
FROM estoque e 
INNER JOIN  produto p ON (e.produto_id = p.id)
WHERE e.dtTransacao BETWEEN @DI AND @DF
GROUP BY e.produto_id
```

**Exception**

[image]

Comment: @GordonLinoff yep, I'm sure. All my project was developed using MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208854/sql-group-by-case-statement-with-aggregate-function

Comment: can you publish the output of `show create table estoque ` and `show create table produto` so I can recreate and hopefully show you the `c#` issue. Also, provide some clarity in what context that `select` stmt is to run (like flat out in `c#` or inside some report-writer stand alone app)